# Can adjectives decorate other adjectives?

Tags: prepositions, adjectives

> They would lead to greater naturalness in the graphic depiction **of
> anatomy, clothingn likeness, expression, and landscape.**

It seems

'of anatomy, clothing, likeness, expression, and landscape'

decorates

'graphic depiction'

But isn't it an adjective? Which decorates 'naturalness'

Adjectives can decorate other adjectives?

Or 'of ~' decorates 'naturalness' ?

Comment: *Depiction* is a noun, as are all of those other words. The only adjectives in the sentence are *greater* and *graphic*. The use of "decorate" here is very odd. Do you mean *modify*? Those other nouns don't modify anything. Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 3):

Your word "decorates" is not appropriate here. I think you mean "modifies".

The quotation seems to be from here:
[Blogspot "art articles"](https://best-art-articles.blogspot.com/2012/09/title-photography-and-its-role-as.html)

> [Francis Wey] suggested that they [photographs] would lead to greater naturalness in the graphic depiction of anatomy, clothing, likeness, expression, and landscape configuration.

The word "naturalness" is followed by a preposition phrase that contains another preposition phrase:
[in the graphic depiction [of anatomy, clothing, likeness, expression and landscape configuration]].

The first preposition phrase has the preposition "in" followed by the noun phrase "the graphic depiction", which has a specifier, an adjective, and a noun.

The second preposition phrase has the preposition "of" followed by a series of nouns. That second phrase modifies "graphic depiction".

The combination of the two preposition phrases modifies "naturalness".

So, it is definitely possible for a noun to be modified by a phrase, which is in turn modified by another phrase.